# Returning generic types from Repository

Tags: c#, generics, repository

Is it bad design if I create repostory with methods that returns generic types. For example in AccountsRepository if I have:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
where T : class
{
}

public class AccountsRepository<TUser> : 
Repository<User>,IAccountsRepository
    where TUser : class,IUser,new()
    {
      public TUser GetUserByUserName(string username)
      {
       return this.context.User.Where(s => 
       s.UserName.Equals(username)).Select(c=>new TUser(){ Password =c.Password }).FirstOrDefault();
      }
    }
```

Is this the proper way of doing that. So It's something like I return DTO object but it is generic type. So my classes using repository doesn't have to know what types are the objects in database.

Comment: I always find it hard to do in a good way. usually you end up having to create methods for a specific type, in your example the type "User" needs a method to find the user by name, most other types don't need that.

Comment: What's `IRepository<T>`? What's the point in empty`Repository<T>` implementation? What's `User` and how does it relate to `IUser` and `TUser`? Too much code is omitted, but if I guessed it right, it feels like this is going to be a needless level of abstraction. Your question lacks explanation on why you think this is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it bad design if I create repostory with methods that returns generic types.

Not at all. It's very useful.

> Is this the proper way of doing that?

I'm not entirely sure because even though you use a generic return type you use the same `User` table for all of them:

> ```
> this.context.User
> ```

However if the `IRepository` provides different `User` tables where each of the different users implement the `TUser` then I'd say it' fine. Otherwise it would not be that usefull and you could just return the *normal* `User`.